# Using <select multiple> in Spring MVC throws java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: spring-mvc, multi-select

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

I'm trying to build a web app using only annotations, java, JSPs, spring data, spring mvc, and mongo db.

I've got things mostly working, however when I tried to create a JSP form with multi select lists, I'm getting the title error.

I'm trying to create an agent object and save it to the mongodb database.  The multi select boxes are passing back string IDs for the objects that were selected.  The agent object has lists that need to be populated with the multi select lists.

Here is the response data from chrome dev tools:

```
id: name:Test1 type:MOB
attributeList[]:687a1964-4179-4631-832b-e23b34300840
personalityTraitList[]:8b321f3c-6398-4bc4-afc6-e6c7e4a6a3e3
skillList[]:53090226-0f54-4121-90c0-4d3a188aa5f8
triggerList[]:923048ef-7a4d-42e3-8691-2d2e9603e79b
behaviorTreeList[]:84966b7a-fb53-4f64-be2a-203ae3743250
```

Here is the html for the first multi select box. They are all the same.

```
<td align="left">
    <select size="10" id="selectedAttributes" multiple="multiple" name="attributeList[${attribute.id}]" style="width: 130px;"></select>
</td>
```

Here is the controller save request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/AgentManager/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public View createAgent(@ModelAttribute Agent agent, ModelMap model) 
{
    if(StringUtils.hasText(agent.getId())) 
    {
        agentService.updateAgent(agent);
    } else 
    {
        agentService.addAgent(agent);
    }

    return new RedirectView("/MotherNatureEmulator/AgentManager");  
}
```

The agent service will create a random UUID if the ID field is empty when going to save the agent.

Here is the stack trace:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>       java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>       java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
>       java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
>       org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:969)
>       org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:902)
>       org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
>       org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:740)
>       org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:636)
>       org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:191)
>       org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:112)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:153)
>       org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:106)
>       org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
>       org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
>       org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

I tried creating a custom data binder, but that didn't help.

Could anyone direct me to the right way to do these things?  This is the first time I'm trying to make a web app by myself.

Here is the Agent class:

```
@Document(collection = "AgentCollection")
public class Agent 
{
@Id
private String _id;

private String _name;
private String _type;
private ArrayList<String> _actionList;
private ArrayList<String> _attributeList;
private ArrayList<String> _behaviorTreeList;
private ArrayList<String> _itemList;
private ArrayList<String> _personalityTraitList;
private ArrayList<String> _skillList;
private ArrayList<String> _triggerList;


public String getId() 
{
    return _id;
}


public void setId(String id) 
{
    _id = id;
}


public String getName() 
{
    return _name;
}


public void setName(String name)
{
    _name = name;
}


public String getType() 
{
    return _type;
}


public void setType(String type)
{
    _type = type;
}


public ArrayList<String> getAttributeList()
{
    return _attributeList;
}


public void setAttributeList(final ArrayList<String> attributeList)
{
    _attributeList = attributeList;
}


public ArrayList<String> getPresonalityTraitList()
{
    return _personalityTraitList;
}


public void setPersonalityTraitList(final ArrayList<String> personalityTraitList)
{
    _personalityTraitList = personalityTraitList;
}


public ArrayList<String> getSkillList()
{
    return _skillList;
}


public void setSkillList(final ArrayList<String> skillList)
{
    _skillList = skillList;
}


public ArrayList<String> getActionList()
{
    return _actionList;
}


public void setActionList(final ArrayList<String> actionList)
{
    _actionList = actionList;
}


public ArrayList<String> getTriggerList()
{
    return _triggerList;
}


public void setTriggerList(final ArrayList<String> triggerList)
{
    _triggerList = triggerList;
}


public ArrayList<String> getItemList()
{
    return _itemList;
}


public void setItemList(final ArrayList<String> itemList)
{
    _itemList = itemList;
}


public ArrayList<String> getBehaviorTreeList()
{
    return _behaviorTreeList;
}


public void setBehaviorTreeList(final ArrayList<String> behaviorTreeList)
{
    _behaviorTreeList = behaviorTreeList;
}
}
```

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: It's pretty self-explanatory: One of the fields on the `Agent` class requires an `int`, but you're sending either nothing or the empty string as a parameter.

Comment: I thought that, but the Agent class has nothing that requires and int, they are all strings. Or lists of strings.

Comment: is id: null or empty based on your chrome dev response data? if yes, it may have to do something. But cant see where .

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm thinking empty.  Here is the ID form input field. <input type="hidden" name="id"> before adding the multi select boxes, I could save an agent.

Comment: follow this link, and dont forget to read the comments, those comments have useful information. hope it guides you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121163/how-to-debug-numberformatexception-somewhere-in-basecommandcontroller-bindandval

Comment: Heh, I forgot about that one; I'll try to remember for the future. That's a tricky bug, but a failure mode that should be easy enough to document.

Comment: `name="attributeList[${attribute.id}]"`  - how does the generated html look like ? Secondly, what's the request being sent ?

Comment: Thanks guys, that was it.  I have two multi select boxes, the first has a list of values, the second is empty and I move items between them.  The second has the name="attributeList[${attribute.id}]" which translates to attributeList[] in the html when rendered.  Thanks both Jimmy and coding_idiot.  I can make a more detailed answer or if someone wants to I'll tag it as the answer. I didn't realize that the empty multiselect was going to have issues populating a list of items to send in the request after it had values.

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't handle empty square bracket. To summarize you can use

- ?myarray[0]=aa&myarray[1]=bb
- ?myarray=aa&myarray=bb

but not

- ?myarray[]=aa&myarray[]=bb

I created the ticket https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11214